# poles and contractions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f$ be a rational function on $X$ and $g:X\rightarrow Y$ be a birational morphism.

What is a pole of $f$?

What does it mean that the poles of $f$ are contracted by $g$?

Comment: I suppose by *a* pole, one would mean an irreducible divisor in $X$ along which $f$ blows up, in other words an irreducible component of $f^{-1}(\infty)$, where we are thinking of $f$ as a morphism $X \to \mathbb P^1$. To say that $g$ contracts poles of $f$ would mean that $g$ is a divisorial contraction whose exceptional locus includes $f^{-1}(\infty)$.

Comment: Is this the same like saying that the discrete valuation $v_D(f)<0$ along $D$ for an irreducible divisor $D$?  Is contraction something like saying that the image of an irreducible divisor has codim $> 1$? You mean a pole is an irreducible divisor. Could a pole be also the sum of such irreducible divisors? (I'm not so familiar with these things so maybe this is a stupid question)

Comment: That's the thing; I usually only hear people talk about poles as singular nouns (as opposed to saying something like "the function has poles along $D$") in the curve/Riemann surface case where poles occur at isolated points, but I see no reason to not say that a sum of irreducible divisors "is a pole" as well. As for your other questions, yes: a pole is where the valuation is negative, and a divisor is contracted if its image has codimension higher than $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!